# Tensorflow with XLA hangs with both GPU and CPU at ~0% usage

Tags: tensorflow, xla

I wanted to try out the XLA backend on tensorflow 1.1.0 which I built from source to support the XLA compiler.  Also I am using Ubuntu 16.04.  My model runs fine without the XLA backend.  It takes about 0.8 seconds to compute a single training step on my GTX 1080 GPU. However when I enable the XLA compiler it makes it up to the point where I make the first call to session.run in my model and then just hangs there.  My CPU and GPU are at about zero usage.

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.graph_options.optimizer_options.global_jit_level = tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1
sess = tf.Session(config = config)
m = model.CharacterTranslator(sess, MAX_LENGTH)
m.init_variables()

best_cost = None
m.restore('/media/chase/98d61322-9ea7-473e-b835-8739c77d1e1e/Translator/model.chk')
while True:
    #session.run is called inside of here
    m.train(random.sample(training_data, 40000), 64, False)
    c = m.train(validation_data, 64, True)[0]
    if best_cost is None or c < best_cost:
        count = 0
        best_cost = c
        print('Saving...')
        m.save('/media/chase/98d61322-9ea7-473e-b835-8739c77d1e1e/Translator/model.chk')
    else:
        count += 1
        if count == 10:
            break


...
    def train(self, training_data, batch_size, validate = False, verbose = True):
            total_cost = 0
            total_acc = 0
            total_time = 0
            last_chars = 0
            total_batches = len(training_data) // batch_size
            for i, batch in enumerate(_batch(training_data, batch_size, False)):
                x, y = zip(*batch)
                x, xl = zip(*[self._vectorize_sent(s) for s in x])
                y, yl = zip(*[self._vectorize_sent(s) for s in y])
                start_time = time.time()
                c, a, g, l, _ = self.session.run((self.cost, self.accuracy, self.global_step, self.learning_rate, self.null_train_step if validate else self.train_step), {
                    self.source_text: x,
                    self.target_text: y,
                    self.target_length: yl,
                    self.teacher_forcing: True,
                })
                end_time = time.time()
                total_cost += c
                total_acc += a
                total_time += end_time - start_time
                if verbose:
                    msg = '%s b(%d / %d) g(%d) c(%e) a(%0.4f) lr(%e) dt(%0.2f)' % ('Validating' if validate else 'Training', i, total_batches, g, total_cost / (i + 1), total_acc / (i + 1), l, total_time / (i + 1))
                    msg += ' ' * max(0, last_chars - len(msg))
                    last_chars = len(msg)
                    print(msg, end = '\r')
            if verbose: 
                print()
            return total_cost / (i + 1), total_acc / (i + 1)
```

It produces the following tensorflow output when I try to run it.

```
2017-04-26 05:15:58.421388: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-04-26 05:15:58.421698: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.33GiB
2017-04-26 05:15:58.421708: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 
2017-04-26 05:15:58.421711: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y 
2017-04-26 05:15:58.421719: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py:93: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
2017-04-26 05:17:17.107616: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform CUDA present with 1 visible devices
2017-04-26 05:17:17.107635: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform Host present with 8 visible devices
2017-04-26 05:17:17.108265: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:183] XLA service 0xa103840 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2017-04-26 05:17:17.108274: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:191]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2017-04-26 05:17:17.108393: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform CUDA present with 1 visible devices
2017-04-26 05:17:17.108398: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform Host present with 8 visible devices
2017-04-26 05:17:17.108602: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:183] XLA service 0xe383100 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2017-04-26 05:17:17.108607: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:191]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1080, Compute Capability 6.1
```

I then attached gdb to the process to see what it was doing.  It looks like it is just sitting on a pthread conditional wait.

```
#0  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:185
#1  0x00007f715569291c in std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007f716d85257b in tensorflow::DirectSession::WaitForNotification(tensorflow::Notification*, long long) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
#3  0x00007f716d85262d in tensorflow::DirectSession::WaitForNotification(tensorflow::DirectSession::RunState*, tensorflow::CancellationManager*, long long) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
#4  0x00007f716d85d287 in tensorflow::DirectSession::Run(tensorflow::RunOptions const&, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, tensorflow::Tensor>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, tensorflow::Tensor> > > const&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor, std::allocator<tensorflow::Tensor> >*, tensorflow::RunMetadata*) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
#5  0x00007f716c3259d1 in TF_Run_Helper(tensorflow::Session*, char const*, TF_Buffer const*, std::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, tensorflow::Tensor>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, tensorflow::Tensor> > > const&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, TF_Tensor**, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, TF_Buffer*, TF_Status*) [clone .constprop.554] ()
   from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
#6  0x00007f716c32639a in TF_Run ()
   from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
#7  0x00007f716c0ab351 in tensorflow::TF_Run_wrapper_helper(TF_DeprecatedSession*, char const*, TF_Buffer const*, _object*, tensorflow::gtl::InlinedVector<char const*, 8> const&, tensorflow::gtl::InlinedVector<char const*, 8> const&, TF_Status*, tensorflow::gtl::InlinedVector<_object*, 8>*, TF_Buffer*) ()
```

Does anyone have any idea why my tensorflow model with the XLA backend gets stuck?

Comment: Curious. Your code looks fine to me. I'd like to debug the problem. Can you please file a Tensorflow Github issue and assign it to me (Github user "hawkinsp")? The key thing I will need to debug is a fully self-contained reproduction of the problem (a version of your code that exhibits the problem but does not have any external code or data dependencies). Thanks!

Comment: I think I can do that.  I will need to send you a few files and a sample of training data.  Probably won't get to it until after work or tomorrow morning.  Also XLA works in predict mode but only hangs when I run the training step.

Comment: I posted it on the issues page but I don't see where I can assign it to you.    https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9509